# Manage an Analytics Account with OAuth and Google Analytics Admin API

Tags: python, google-analytics, oauth, google-analytics-api

I'm trying to use the Google Analytics Admin API to access properties and manage settings (trying to link Google Analytics and Google Ads when a client requests that we manage their ads). Ideally this would be done through OAuth and them granting access right from the browser when they sign up. However, if there's a way to send an management invite like with Google Ads accounts that would work too.

I tried setting up a service account but couldn't figure out how to give it access to an account. Then I tried granting access using OAuth, which I was able to get a token from but I'm not able to use that token with the AnalyticsAdminServiceClient library (or at least can't figure out how).

Here's what I tried with OAuth:

```py
import yaml
from google.analytics.admin import AnalyticsAdminServiceClient

yaml_file = open('./oauth_analytics.yaml')
parsed_yaml_file = yaml.load(yaml_file, Loader=yaml.FullLoader)

test_auth_code = parsed_yaml_file['test_auth_code']
client_id = parsed_yaml_file['client_id']
client_secret = parsed_yaml_file['client_secret']

#get a refresh token
from google.oauth2.credentials import Credentials

credentials = Credentials(
    None,
    refresh_token=test_auth_code,
    token_uri="https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token",
    client_id=client_id,
    client_secret=client_secret
)

# Use the refresh token to obtain an access token.
client = AnalyticsAdminServiceClient(credentials=credentials)

print(client.list_accounts())
```

\When I run that code I get the following exception:

`google.api_core.exceptions.Unauthenticated: 401 Request had invalid authentication credentials. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential.`

I found this question answer which shows the same method I'm using (but I'm assuming it worked for them, there's probably something obvious I'm missing): [How do I call Google Analytics Admin API (for GA4) using an OAuth2 client in node.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74565080/how-do-i-call-google-analytics-admin-api-for-ga4-using-an-oauth2-client-in-nod)

Comment: You forgot the code to actually authorize the call.

Comment: what do you mean? I already got the auth code when I originally granted permission, is there something else I need to do?

Comment: Maybe follow the python [sample](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/admin/v1/quickstart-client-libraries#python)

Comment: That's what I was following but I was unable to give the service account access to an analytics property and there was no documentation on how to do that so I switched to trying using OAuth to grant access.

Comment: Thats a completely different question.   Maybe you should have asked that first :)

Comment: Oh huh I thought that is what I asked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use Oauth2 instead of a service account your code should look more like this

```
from google.analytics.admin import AnalyticsAdminServiceClient

# pip install google-analytics-admin

CREDENTIALS_FILE_PATH = 'C:\Development\FreeLance\GoogleSamples\Credentials\credentials.json'
GA4_PROPERTY_ID = '250796939'

from google_auth_oauthlib import flow

def list_accounts(credentials=None):
    """
    Lists the available Google Analytics accounts.

    Args:

    """
    # Using a default constructor instructs the client to use the credentials
    # specified in GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS environment variable.
    client = AnalyticsAdminServiceClient(credentials=credentials)

    request = AnalyticsAdminServiceClient.ListAccountSummariesRequest()
    request.page_size = 1

    # Make the request
    results = client.list_account_summaries(page_size = 1)

    # Displays the configuration information for all Google Analytics accounts
    # available to the authenticated user.
    print("Result:")
    for account in results:
        print(account)

def get_credentials():
    """Creates an OAuth2 credentials instance."""

    appflow = flow.InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(
        CREDENTIALS_FILE_PATH,
        scopes=["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly"],
    )
    # TODO(developer): Update the line below to set the `launch_browser` variable.
    # The `launch_browser` boolean variable indicates if a local server is used
    # as the callback URL in the auth flow. A value of `True` is recommended,
    # but a local server does not work if accessing the application remotely,
    # such as over SSH or from a remote Jupyter notebook.
    launch_browser = True
    if launch_browser:
        appflow.run_local_server()
    else:
        # note yes this is deprecated.  It will work if you change the redirect uri in the url given you from urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob
        # to http://127.0.0.1  The client library team needs to fix this.
        appflow.run_console()
    return appflow.credentials



def main():
    credentials = get_credentials()
    list_accounts(credentials)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Where do I get the credentials in your example? When I try to tun that with my service account credentials I get an error: `ValueError: Client secrets must be for a web or installed app.`

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood. try this.

Comment: Is there a way to request the access programatically? Or can I access the same features on the account through OAuth instead of a service account? We're trying to make it as simple as possible for our clients.

Comment: No a service account needs to be granted access directly though the google analytics account.   If you want to make it as simple as possible for your clients. Do it how my other clients have done have them grant you access then use Oauth2 to access your script.

Comment: Are you saying there's no way to manage the account through an oauth link gaining an access token for their account?

Comment: Use oauth2 and request access of a user with access and store the refresh token.   Or use a service account and have them pre-authorize it by adding it as a user.    These are your options

Comment: Yeah I want to do the first option.

Comment: They you want the other code i gave you and switch to using a oauth2 client

Comment: Aha your code pointed me in the right direction, thank you!